Can someone explain strange behavior trying to plot a non-differentiable function?
I have some data that I am using to generate a non-differentiable function and trying to plot it in R and I am observing unexpected behavior: namely, the output of the function during plotting seems to be different than if R calculates the value of the function.
Creating the data
v1 <- c(3.323,4.0034,4.6584,5.2826)
v2 <- c(1200,1300,1400,1500)
data <- cbind(v1, v2)

creating the function
fun <- function(x){
  ans <- NA
  ans[x >= data[1,1] & x <= data[2,1]] <- 100*(x-data[1,1])/(data[2,1]-data[1,1])+data[1,2]
  ans[x >= data[2,1] & x <= data[3,1]] <- 100*(x-data[2,1])/(data[3,1]-data[2,1])+data[2,2]
  ans[x >= data[3,1] & x <= data[4,1]] <- 100*(x-data[3,1])/(data[4,1]-data[3,1])+data[3,2]
  ans
  }

If I evaluate the function at various points I get what I expect
> fun(4.3309)
[1] 1350

> fun(4.0034)
[1] 1300

etc...
If I try to plot the function
plot(fun, type = 'l', xlim = c(3.323,5.2826))

I get warning messages

1: In ans[x >= data[1, 1] & x <= data[2, 1]] <- 100 * (x - data[1,  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In ans[x >= data[2, 1] & x <= data[3, 1]] <- 100 * (x - data[2,  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In ans[x >= data[3, 1] & x <= data[4, 1]] <- 100 * (x - data[3,  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

and a plot that does not match if I just evaluate the function after the first non-differentiation point (if that is the right term)


The answer will have to do with vectorization (or lack thereof) of your function. plot.function() calls curve(), which tries to evaluate the function simultaneously (i.e., by passing a vector) at (by default) n=101 points ...

Your definition looks wrong:  you say x >= data[1,1] & x <= data[2,1] in the first condition, and x >= data[2,1] & x <= data[3,1] in the second.  That means x == data[2,1] matches both, and is assigned twice.  But the cause of your error is that you subset the destination in each assignment, but don't subset x in the value being assigned.

I realize that the <= and >= means that the boundary point is assigned twice but that was me being lazy as I had defined it before with >= and < conditions with the same error. Ultimately this is strictly for "quality control" in defining the function as the intended plot is the "same" as plot(data, type = "l", xlim = c(3.323,5.2826))

Your warning comes from below, for example
ans[x >= data[1,1] & x <= data[2,1]] <- 100*(x-data[1,1])/(data[2,1]-data[1,1])+data[1,2]

where the length of ans[x >= data[1,1] & x <= data[2,1]] is shorter than x, while on the right-hand-side term, 100*(x-data[1,1])/(data[2,1]-data[1,1])+data[1,2] is of the same length of x

You can try either of the following options
fun <- function(x) {
    ans <- NA
    msk1 <- x >= data[1, 1] & x <= data[2, 1]
    ans[msk1] <- 100 * (x[msk1] - data[1, 1]) / (data[2, 1] - data[1, 1]) + data[1, 2]
    msk2 <- x >= data[2, 1] & x <= data[3, 1]
    ans[msk2] <- 100 * (x[msk2] - data[2, 1]) / (data[3, 1] - data[2, 1]) + data[2, 2]
    msk3 <- x >= data[3, 1] & x <= data[4, 1]
    ans[msk3] <- 100 * (x[msk3] - data[3, 1]) / (data[4, 1] - data[3, 1]) + data[3, 2]
    ans
}

or
fun <- Vectorize(function(x) {
    ans <- NA
    ans[x >= data[1, 1] & x <= data[2, 1]] <- 100 * (x - data[1, 1]) / (data[2, 1] - data[1, 1]) + data[1, 2]
    ans[x >= data[2, 1] & x <= data[3, 1]] <- 100 * (x - data[2, 1]) / (data[3, 1] - data[2, 1]) + data[2, 2]
    ans[x >= data[3, 1] & x <= data[4, 1]] <- 100 * (x - data[3, 1]) / (data[4, 1] - data[3, 1]) + data[3, 2]
    ans
})

and I believe the warning would be resolved.
